# Datepicker onChange issue React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On datepicker I have an `onChange` event. The problem is when a user starts to manually change date.

if user only changes day, the `onChange` function is called and will send req for data.

And if user continue to make changes manually, every time `onChange` is executed, which causes performance issue.

How can I avoid this problem?

Sample of Datepicker code:

```
 <Form.Field>
   <label style={{ float: 'left' }}>From</label>
   <input
     ref={i => {
       this.reportDateStartedField = i
       }}
     onChange={this.handleFieldChange.bind(this)}
     type="date"
     name="reportDateStarted"
     value={filters.reportDateStarted}
     max={todayDate}
     style={{ fontSize: '0.9em' }}
    />
```

Comment: Generally that's `onChange` purpose. If you don't want to track all the changes by the user you should use an `onClick` listener but that means that the user has to press a button or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not call it a performance issue. Since react follows one way data binding, it is up the the developer to decide when to call the render(or defer rendering). Virtual DOM should be in sync.

On the side note you could use 'onBlur' instead of 'onChange' to trigger change only when user has finished typing and focused out.

```
<Form.Field>
   <label style={{ float: 'left' }}>From</label>
   <input
     ref={i => {
       this.reportDateStartedField = i
       }}
     onBlur={this.handleFieldChange.bind(this)}
     type="date"
     name="reportDateStarted"
     defaultValue={filters.reportDateStarted}
     max={todayDate}
     style={{ fontSize: '0.9em' }}
    />
```

In above case the input will be 'uncontrolled' (defaultValue) since react is not aware of the change until user focus out of the input.

Comment: onBlur is nice idea, but does not work in this case. When I change date, app does not made change. It's forzen current date.

Comment: In that case you could use defaultValue={filters.reportDateStarted} since you are not controlling the field

Comment: I need to use onBlur for manual input, as to not run onChange as the user manually inputs a data. But, if the users selected a date from the calendar drop down, that should fire onChange. Right now, having onChange fires when there is any manual input, then onBlur fires when the user clicks out of the input field. 
How would I ensure onBlur only fires for manual input and onChange only fires when the user selects a date from the drop down calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution would be to not use the `onChange` event to fetch data but only use it to control the input and have a button `onClick` to do the fetching.

Comment: When I use onClick, then when user click to open Date-picker function is executed, but he didnt select date. It's not the best solution.

Comment: I mean onClick on a seperate button, e.g. `<button onClick={goFetchData}>Fetch Data</button>`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with react js.

> When I change
>   date, app does not made change. It's forzen current date.

I have solved this issue by using `onFocus` instead of `onBlur` or `onClick` since datepicker automatically focuses on text field which does made the change (in my case). Also, use `onChange` on top of `onFocus` if needed.

```
<Form.Field>
   <label style={{ float: 'left' }}>From</label>
   <input
     ref={i => {
       this.reportDateStartedField = i
       }}
     onFocus={this.handleFieldChange}
     onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
     type="date"
     name="reportDateStarted"
     defaultValue={filters.reportDateStarted}
     max={todayDate}
     style={{ fontSize: '0.9em' }}
    />
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your onFocus idea but it made it to where I couldn't manually input a date, only select from the calendar drop down.

I need to use onBlur for manual input, as to not run onChange as the user manually inputs a data. But, if the users selected a date from the calendar drop down, that should fire onChange. Right now, having onChange fires when there is any manual input, then onBlur fires when the user clicks out of the input field. 
How would I ensure onBlur only fires for manual input and onChange only fires when the user selects a date from the drop down calendar?